# how to create after update trigger in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Dear friends I have one table "terms_marks" in which we create an trigger "trgcreatetotal" but when we update an specific column "SA1" in table terms_marks it will give the  following error . I already done lot of googling . but i have not found solution.

"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgcreatetotal, Line 11
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated."

so please any one can suggest us how it will we resolve  please

Thanks.........

```
database table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[terms_marks](
 [marksmaster_id_] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [term_id] [int] NULL,
 [st_id] [int] NULL,
 [sub_id] [int] NULL,
 [roll_no] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [admission_no] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [FA1] [int] NULL,
 [FA2] [int] NULL,
 [SA1] [int] NULL,
 [Total_FirstTerm] [int] NULL,
 [FA3] [int] NULL,
 [FA4] [int] NULL,
 [SA2] [int] NULL,
 [Total_SecondTerm] [int] NULL,
 [Total_FA] [int] NULL,
 [Total_SA] [int] NULL,
 [GrandTotal] [int] NULL,
 [maxmarks] [int] NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

trigger code here

```
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

 create trigger [dbo].[trgcreatetotal] on [dbo].[terms_marks]
  AFTER  UPDATE
  AS
  declare @std_id int;
  IF UPDATE(SA1)
  begin
  SELECT @std_id = st_id   
  FROM   inserted
  UPDATE T
  SET T.Total_FirstTerm= (select (FA1+FA2))
  from terms_marks T
  INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T.st_id=I.st_id
  WHERE T.Total_FirstTerm IS NULL
update terms_marks set Total_FirstTerm=(select(FA1+FA2))where st_id=@std_id

END
GO
```

Comment: Once more: Trigger work per entire statement not row by row

Comment: Thanks your reply but i don't understand what you say please clarify and where is problem in code please notify me.

Comment: @user2342574 If you run update query which affects 20 rows, the trigger will fire once for this update.